# Finding Filtered Output using Convolution property of Continuous Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier, convolution

why the derivative of u[t] is delta[t] ? 
also I don't understand why the sin term disappeared once the derivative is taken. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$\delta (t)\$ is the unit impulse and is zero everywhere except at \$t=0\$, and \$sin\:(\omega _0 t)=0\$ at \$t=0\$. The product of these two is zero everywhere.

\$u(t)\$ is the unit step function and its derivative is infinite at \$t=0\$ and zero everywhere else, and this is the definition of the unit impulse.